# Retrieve the subjects that have at most two properties

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, rdfs

I wanted to retrive subjects which have less than three properties. I tried with following query.

```
SELECT ?s
WHERE {
 ?s ?p ?o .
}
group by ?s
having (count(?p) < 3)
limit 10
```

But it's taking quite long time. Do we have any other optimized way to do same thing.

Comment: nope, that's the intended way to do in a single query. If you have some property or class that would partition the subjects, you could do in multiple separate queries for each partition

Comment: "taking time" by the way also depends on hardware, size of the data and the triple store being used. But the query plan is most likely the same for all triple stores as this query is rather basic, no joins or anything at all. Indeed, early termination is possible because of the `LIMIT 10` - but it depends on when the first 10 of those subjects have been found. Could be the case that up to the last subject in the graph being touched and the limit never has been exceeded before. So you did process all subjects